# How to show data from two different SQL tables in ListView according to requirement

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, listview, dataset

I Have a ListView and a Database with two tables, i have a Linq search query, **when a person selects groom radio button and hits search it has to show data from Male table into the ListView** and **when person selects bride radio button and hits search it should show data from Female table in the ListView** how can i manage it

```
protected void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (WebTechManiaDataContext Data = new WebTechManiaDataContext())
        {
            string Education = DropDownListEducation.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
            string MaritalStatus = DropDownListMaritalStatus.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();

            if (RadioButtonGroom.Checked == true | RadioButtonBride.Checked == false)
            {
                if ((DropDownListFrom.SelectedItem.Text == "21") && (DropDownListTo.SelectedItem.Text == "22"))
                {
                    var FoundGroom = Data.Males.Where(Males => (Males.Age == 21 || Males.Age == 22) && (Males.Education == Education || Education.Length == 0) && (Males.CurrentStatus == MaritalStatus || MaritalStatus.Length == 0));
                    if (!FoundGroom.Any())
                    {
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Search result Negetive');</script>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ListViewResult.DataSourceID = "LinqDataSourceGroom";
                        ListViewResult.DataSource = FoundGroom;
                        ListViewResult.DataBind();
                    }
                }
                else if ((DropDownListFrom.SelectedItem.Text == "21") && (DropDownListTo.SelectedItem.Text == "23"))
                {
                    var FoundGroom = Data.Males.Where(Males => (Males.Age == 21 || Males.Age == 22 || Males.Age == 23) && (Males.Education == Education || Education.Length == 0) && (Males.CurrentStatus == MaritalStatus || MaritalStatus.Length == 0));
                    if (!FoundGroom.Any())
                    {
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Search result Negetive');</script>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ListViewResult.DataSourceID = "LinqDataSourceGroom";
                        ListViewResult.DataSource = FoundGroom;
                        ListViewResult.DataBind();
                    }
                }

                else if ((DropDownListFrom.SelectedItem.Text == "21") && (DropDownListTo.SelectedItem.Text == "24"))
                {
                    var FoundGroom = Data.Males.Where(Males => (Males.Age == 21 || Males.Age == 22 || Males.Age == 23 || Males.Age == 24) && (Males.Education == Education || Education.Length == 0) && (Males.CurrentStatus == MaritalStatus || MaritalStatus.Length == 0));
                    if (!FoundGroom.Any())
                    {
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Search result Negetive');</script>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ListViewResult.DataSourceID = "LinqDataSourceGroom";
                        ListViewResult.DataSource = FoundGroom;
                        ListViewResult.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (RadioButtonBride.Checked == true | RadioButtonBride.Checked == false)
            {
                if ((DropDownListFrom.SelectedItem.Text == "21") && (DropDownListTo.SelectedItem.Text == "22"))
                {
                    var FoundBride = Data.Females.Where(Females => (Females.Age == 21 || Females.Age == 22) && (Females.Education == Education || Education.Length == 0) && (Females.CurrentStatus == MaritalStatus || MaritalStatus.Length == 0));
                    if (!FoundBride.Any())
                    {
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Search result Negetive');</script>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ListViewResult.DataSourceID = "LinqDataSourceBride";
                        ListViewResult.DataSource = FoundBride;
                        ListViewResult.DataBind();
                    }
                }
                else if ((DropDownListFrom.SelectedItem.Text == "21") && (DropDownListTo.SelectedItem.Text == "23"))
                {
                    var FoundBride = Data.Females.Where(Females => (Females.Age == 21 || Females.Age == 22 || Females.Age == 23) && (Females.Education == Education || Education.Length == 0) && (Females.CurrentStatus == MaritalStatus || MaritalStatus.Length == 0));
                    if (!FoundBride.Any())
                    {
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Search result Negetive');</script>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ListViewResult.DataSourceID = "LinqDataSourceBride";
                        ListViewResult.DataSource = FoundBride;
                        ListViewResult.DataBind();
                    }
                }

                else if ((DropDownListFrom.SelectedItem.Text == "21") && (DropDownListTo.SelectedItem.Text == "24"))
                {
                    var FoundBride = Data.Females.Where(Females => (Females.Age == 21 || Females.Age == 22 || Females.Age == 23 || Females.Age == 24) && (Females.Education == Education || Education.Length == 0) && (Females.CurrentStatus == MaritalStatus || MaritalStatus.Length == 0));
                    if (!FoundBride.Any())
                    {
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Search result Negetive');</script>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ListViewResult.DataSourceID = "LinqDataSourceBride";
                        ListViewResult.DataSource = FoundBride;
                        ListViewResult.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `else if (RadioButtonBride.Checked == true | RadioButtonBride.Checked == false)` this is always true.

Comment: that code is fine, but i need to show data from two different tables in ListView ,see my question..

Comment: As far as how you can manage it goes, I suggest breaking down your if statements into one method instead of chaining them together. Also take a look at int.Parse(). If you have integer values as string in your dropdown list, you don't need to check for their string value in one line and hardcode their int values in the next.